# How to use PrintServer and PrintQueue classes

Tags: c#, .net, printing

Is using the `PrintServer` and `PrintQueue` classes the same as looking at the jobs via the printer in Windows?

We have an application that can print to a windows printer directly, but it cannot create a byte array or anything similar that we could use to call `AddJob`.  Would enumerating the printer using the `PrintQueue.GetPrintJobInfoCollection()` method work for checking the status of the original printed item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe so.  See the example in [How to: Diagnose Problematic Print Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-diagnose-problematic-print-job).  The article illustrates the use of `PrintServer` & `PrintQueue` to identify problematic print jobs.

Here's code project article that uses WMI for enumerating print job : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/prntjobcontrollerusingwmi.aspx

Comment: Hmmm, strangely enough that MSDN article is dead.

Comment: @JeremyThompson, article still exists for previous .NET versions - e.g. check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970685%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: G'day @VinayC, thanks for heads up mate, I'll edit answer accordingly :)